Implication of Minimum generating Set in Polynomial time
Recently I came across an interesting work showing that the Minimum Generating Set problem for a finite group $G$ can be solved in polynomial time https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869323005720.
I am curious to know, what is the implication of this result on the computational complexity of other problems in group theory or algorithms? Specifically, which other problems could potentially be solved in polynomial time or with improved complexity?
Also, I was wondering will it have any implication on the group isomorphism problem? Can someone please give insight on this.

This result represents a significant advance in the area, and the algorithm in question can be effectively implemented with good performace, but it should be emphasized that the complexity is polynomial in $|G|$ which is not ideal when working with permutation groups. I cannot see any immediate theoretical application to the isomorphism problem, although it would be likely to be helpful in implementations.
